# Liquid Pockets in Cream Cheese

Tags: cream-cheese

I have a maybe (3 lb?) block of Philadelphia Brand Cream Cheese. I just cut into it for the third time and noticed several pockets of what appear to be to be water in the middle of the cheese. I've never seen that before and wonder if anybody knows what causes it. It's well within its expected freshness time, has always been refrigerated and carefully wrapped. The pockets of clear liquid range from 1-2 square centimeters, and are right in the middle of the cheese. The cheese tastes and smells perfectly normal. Can anybody say what this is?

Comment: It sounds like whey.  Evidently your block was insufficiently strained before being pressed into the mold.

Comment: Strange to find that in such a well known brand, but without another explanation it sounds right. How 'bout putting it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like whey.  Evidently your block was insufficiently strained before being pressed into the mold.